# Setting the width of the button in android

Tags: android, button

Is it possible to set the width of the button while clicking the same button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
int pixels = 30;

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setWidth(pixels);
    }
});
```